# PHP sessions and its use in interlinked pages also page redirection

Tags: php, forms, session, redirect

I have a question .
This is the scope of the question :

Prepare a registration form on php and while submiting the data it will go to next page .Give link to a third page and Use sessions to  print the collected data on this page.

I'm new to it so not really sure how to continue but I have prepared a form .It is as follows

```
      <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
       <html>
       <head>

      </head>
       <body> 
       <h2> Form  Example</h2>

       <form method="post" action="">  
      Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="">

       <br><br>
      Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="">

       <br><br>
       Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
      <br><br>
       Gender:
     <input type="radio" name="gender"  value="female">Female
     <input type="radio" name="gender"  value="male">Male

    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
  </form>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Kindly guide me on how to continue further

Comment: check some tutorials in online and continue further

Comment: at the top of each page use `session_start()` and whatever information you save into the session variables should be available on each of the subsequent after form submission

Comment: Sounds like a homework question to me

Answer (score 0):

Use session variable for this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>  
   <html>
   <head>

  </head>
   <body> 
   <h2> Form  Example</h2>

   //add the redirect page
   <form method="post" action="redirect_page.php">  
  Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="">

   <br><br>
  Address: <input type="text" name="address" value="">

   <br><br>
   Comment: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
  <br><br>
   Gender:
 <input type="radio" name="gender"  value="female">Female
 <input type="radio" name="gender"  value="male">Male

<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

the redirect_page.php in the action should have the following code.

```
<?php session_start();

//submitted button created session variabale
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
{
    $_SESSION['submit']['name'] = $_POST['name'];

    $_SESSION['submit']['comment'] = $_POST['comment'];

    $_SESSION['submit']['gender'] = $_POST['gender'];
}

foreach ($_SESSION['submit'] as $key => $value)
{
    echo $key. ' = ' .$value.'</br>';
}
?>

//third Page Link
<a href ="thirdpage.php">Third Page</a>
```

the third page named thirdpage.php need only to have the fowllowing code. Because session submit already exists thanks to redirect_page.php has create for us!

```
 <?php session_start();
    foreach ($_SESSION['submit'] as $key => $value)
    {
       echo $key. ' = ' .$value.'</br>';
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: how about the link to the third page?what should the third page contain?

Comment: yes.Should we include a link for the third page as mentioned in the question.